# What if neither the president nor vice president is chosen by inauguration day?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, congress, political-transitions

The US election law says that the Senate picks the VP and the House picks the President.

If no president is elected when the term starts, the newly elected VP would act as President.

In such case, what if Senate was also tied 50-50 and fails to elect a new VP?

I see a related thread saying that it is unclear that the sitting VP would be able to cast a tie breaking vote.

Does this mean the US would be without a President (even an acting one) at the start of the new term?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Congress keeps on voting until someone gets picked. If the House of Representatives is unable to decide by inauguration day then the Vice President takes office until they decide. If both the House of Representatives and the Senate is unable to decide by inauguration day the next in line that is eligible  takes office until they decide. The first in line would be the Speaker of the House.

As for the tie breaking vote as the Senate decides who the Vice President they would have no say in a tie breaking vote.

No matter how long it takes congress to decide there will be someone holding the office until they do.

[Contingent election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_election)

President - House of Representatives

> If no candidate for president receives an absolute majority of the
> electoral votes, pursuant to the 12th Amendment, the House of
> Representatives must go into session immediately to choose a president
> from among the three candidates who received the most electoral votes.
> Each state delegation votes en bloc, with each having a single vote. A
> candidate must receive an absolute majority of state delegation votes
> (currently 26 votes) to become president-elect. The House continues
> balloting until it elects a president. As a consequence of the en bloc
> voting, the party that holds the majority in the House could lose the
> contingent election if the minority party holds the majority of state
> delegations. The District of Columbia, which is not a state, does
> not participate; the 23rd Amendment, which granted electoral votes to
> the district, does not grant the District of Columbia a vote in
> contingent elections.

Vice President - Senate

> If no candidate for vice president receives a majority of the
> electoral votes, pursuant to the 12th Amendment, the Senate is
> required to go into session immediately to choose the vice president
> from the two candidates receiving the most electoral votes. Unlike in
> the House, senators cast votes individually. In a contingent election,
> the Senate votes separately from the House, so the president chosen by
> the House and the vice president chosen by the Senate could be from
> different parties.

Comment: It didn't strike me until just now, but it's actually fairly logical that the order is President -> VP -> Leader of the body that chooses the president -> (Nominal) Leader of the body that chooses the VP, even though the Senate is the "higher" house.

Comment: I dread to think what if the house also fails to elect a speaker by inauguration and senate would not have a president (as it would be deadlocked 50-50). :)